# Is there anyway to disable toolbars when starting Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I installed Google Chrome Portable on the user's desktop and have the default homepage set to my website.  How do I disable all toolbars when the user open my shortcut to Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 'kiosk mode' you will hide all browser toolbars and status bar if that's what you want:

http://www.ithinkdiff.com/latest-google-chrome-update-gets-a-kiosk-mode/

Comment: That's pretty good to know.  I am not on that project anymore, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There's also app mode (--app=[url]). Unfortunately, both --app and --kiosk are limited to a single monitor on a multi-monitor setup in Linux.